# JavaScript 2D array setting value to wrong coordinations

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make 2D field:

```
var field=[];
    N = 8;
    M = 12;

for (Y=0;Y<M;Y++){

  for (X=0;X<N;X++){
    field[X,Y]=0;      //trying to make 2d field with coordinates X,Y
  }; 
};

function functiontest(){
  field[3,10]=1;      //trying to set to coordinates "3,10" value 1
  alert(field[2,10]);   //ALERTS 1 for some reason
};
```

I'm trying to set value 1 to coordinates "`3`, `10`" ,but it sets value 1 to all coordinates, which have second coordinates (X,10). When I add script, that sets blue background to DIV with value 1 (id is same as coordinates), it sets it for the whole line.

```
function functionblue(){
  for (Y=0;Y<M;Y++){
    for (X=0;X<N;Z++){
      if (field[X,Y]==0){
        $("#z"+X+""+Y).css("background","blue");     //Divs and its IDs work properly
      }; 
    };
  };
};
```

**[Image Link](http://oi59.tinypic.com/315h2k1.jpg)**.

so how do I set value just toto one point (not line)?

Comment: Change `field[X,Y]` to `field[X][Y]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for a 8 × 10 field

```
n= 8;
m= 12;
var field1= new Array(n);

for (Y=0;Y<n;Y++){
  var field2= new Array(m);
  for (X=0;X<m;X++){
    field2[X]=0;
  }; 
  field1[Y]= field2;
};

function functiontest(){
  field1[3][10]=1;     
  alert(field1[2][10]);
};
```

Comment: This was a very helpfull answer, functionblue() with the change @thefourtheye mentioned works properly now. Thank you!